# How to list all project dependencies in Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle

I want to get all the project dependencies (local jar paths) in my gradle plugin. I try this below in plugin-gradle, but it didn't work as expected.

```
project.configurations.each {conf ->
    println("config ${conf.name}")
    /*try {
        conf.resolvedConfiguration.files.each {
            println("files=" + it.absolutePath)
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace()
    }*/
    /*conf.files.each {
        println("files=" + it.absolutePath)
    }*/
    /*conf.resolve().each {
        println("file " + it.absolutePath)
    }*/
    conf.allDependencies.each {dep->
        println("depends " + dep.name)
    }
    conf.allArtifacts.each {artifact ->
        println("arti=${artifact.file.absolutePath}")
    }
}
```

and this is my project build.gradle (snippet)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    provided fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'provided')
    compile project(':plugin-lib')
}
apply plugin: 'plugin-gradle'
```

also tried as follows, but got an error `Resolving configuration 'provided' directly is not allowed`

```
project.configurations.provided.files.each {
    println("provided " + it.absolutePath)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

android studio 3.5

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

1. create a demo android app.
2. add code at build.gradle.
3. terminal : ./gradlew showAllDependenciesDebug

   //task name : showAllDependencies[Flavor][BuildType]

The result show all sdk(s) info,
include that imported by : 'implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])'

```
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.ArtifactUtils
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.dependencies.BuildMappingUtils
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformManager
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.publishing.AndroidArtifacts
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.VariantScopeImpl


project.afterEvaluate {
    project.android.applicationVariants.each {variant ->
        project.tasks.create(name : "showAllDependencies${variant.name.capitalize()}", group : "help", description: "Print all sdk(s) infomation. author:sodino") {
            doLast {
                showAllDeps(project, variant)
            }
        }
    }
}

def showAllDeps(def project, def variant) {
        def android = project.android
        def globalScope = android.globalScope
        def gradle = project.gradle
        def set = ArtifactUtils.getAllArtifacts(
             new VariantScopeImpl(globalScope,
                new TransformManager(project,
                                    null,
                                    null),
                                    variant.variantData),
             AndroidArtifacts.ConsumedConfigType.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH,
             null,
             BuildMappingUtils.computeBuildMapping(gradle)
        )
        println "${variant.name.capitalize()} all dependencies.size=${set.size()}" 
        set.eachWithIndex {artifact, idx->
                    def componentIdentifier = artifact.componentIdentifier
                    if (componentIdentifier.displayName.contains(':')) {
                        def modulerIdentifier = componentIdentifier.moduleIdentifier
                        def group = modulerIdentifier.group
                        def name = modulerIdentifier.name
                        def version = componentIdentifier.version
                        println "${idx} : ${componentIdentifier.displayName}"
                    } else {
                          println "${idx} -> ${artifact.artifactFile}"
                    }
        }
}
```

The result:

```
sodino Macbook-pro: MyApplication  sodino$: ./gradlew showAllDependenciesDebug

> Configure project :app

> Task :app:showAllDependenciesDebug
Debug all dependencies.size=65
0 -> /Users/sodino/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/libs/sodino.xiamen.FJ.aar
1 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.41
2 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.41
3 : androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.1.0
4 : androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0
5 : com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
6 : androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0
7 : androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0
8 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
9 : androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3
10 : androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0
11 : androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0
12 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0
13 : androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.1.0
14 : androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.1.0
15 : androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.0.0
16 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.1.0
17 : androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.1.0
18 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1
19 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1
20 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.41
21 : androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0
22 : androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0
23 : androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0
24 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
25 : androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
26 : androidx.media:media:1.0.0
27 : androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
28 : androidx.transition:transition:1.0.1
29 : androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
30 : androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
31 : androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:2.1.0
32 : androidx.activity:activity:1.0.0
33 : androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0
34 : androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0
35 : androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0
36 : androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
37 : androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
38 : androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
39 : androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
40 : androidx.navigation:navigation-common:2.1.0
41 : androidx.core:core:1.1.0
42 : androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0
43 : androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0
44 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.1.0
45 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.1.0
46 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0
47 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.1.0
48 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.1.0
49 : androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0
50 : androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0
51 : androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0
52 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0
53 : androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0
54 : androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0
55 : androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0
56 : androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0
57 : androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0
58 : androidx.print:print:1.0.0
59 : androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0
60 : androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0
61 : androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.3
62 : org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:1.1.1
63 : org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.3.41
64 : org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
```